# Organization Membership Payment page not recording memberships

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, profile

As background information, all of our client's members are organizations. I see that if I select "on behalf of organization" and "membership section enabled" I get two copies of the profile on my page. So we won't do that.

However, neither option by itself records a membership in the membership dashboard when the profile is filled out in our tests. I have all the key fields; organization name, email, contact address and phone. I get no errors when saving the contribution page. I have no errors when submitting a live form. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you seeing the other info submitted in the profile?  What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's being deposited into the individual user profile,  but I don't see an associated membership and if I try a new fictional organization, that name is not added as a new contact.

Comment: Have you done anything that would have altered the Employee of/ Employer of Relationship? as that is the basis of 'on behalf of'. If you are trying to record memberships without collecting any Individuals data then i think you will have problems doing so in civi pure. you may succeed via Drupal Webform or WP Caldera as they may sidestep that requirement

Comment: also perhaps add screenshots of you mean by 'two copies of profile'

Comment: Do I need to use the employee/employer relationship or can I use a custom relationship that I've created? We have somewhat complex relationships with organization members, organization administrators and 3rd party associate firms and their various contacts.

Answer (score 3):

After much frustration and subsequent soul searching, contemplating the abyss of total consumption by the digital realm, a singular epiphany presented itself to me at the gates of Valhalla. It whispered in my ear, "you're using the wrong damn profile, you dimwit!"

I had built a custom profile where I should have used the default "on behalf of organization" profile. Much confusion ensued, until I figured out, what is now obvious.

Many thanks for all the help offered and time invested by those who guided this spirit quest.

Comment: Hmmm I cannot seem to be able to select this as an "Include Profile" option? What am I missing here.